# Program is not printing spaces and puncuation

Tags: c, caesar-cipher, cs50

This code is supposed to encipher text based off the command argument input key and print out the enciphered text. However it doesn't print spaces and punctuation.  Can someone explain what is wrong?

Example use:

```
$ ./caesar 12
world, say hello!
iadxp, emk tqxxa!
$
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc>2 || argc<2)
    {
        printf("Please enter a valid argument.\n");
        return 1;
    }  

    string input = GetString();

    int key = atoi(argv[1]);

    for(int i = 0, l = strlen(input); i < l; i++)
    {
        //if(isalpha(input[i]))
        //{
            char c = input[i];
            int letternum = c;

            if(isupper(c))
            {
                int upper = 'A';
                int alphanum = letternum - upper;

                int newint = (alphanum + key) % 26;

                newint = newint + upper;

                char newchar = newint;

                printf("%c", newchar);
            }

            if(islower(c))
            {
                int lower = 'a';
                int alphanum = letternum - lower;

                int newint = (alphanum + key) % 26;

                newint = newint + lower;

                char newchar = newint;

                printf("%c", newchar);
            }
        //}

    }    

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Where is the code and show us how you're   running it and the expected output.

Comment: It is in line 42 (it always is), column 23. Seriously: You tell what is wrong what you expect and show your code. See [ask].

Comment: Consider using `isalpha` to determine if the character is a letter to be encyphered, otherwise output the character "as is".

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot to put in the code. Please see it now.

Answer (score 1):

Add `else` after  `if()` blocks.

Change from

```
       if(isupper(c)) {
         ...
       }
       if(islower(c)) {
         ...
       }
```

to

```
       if(isupper(c)) {
         ...
       } else if(islower(c)) {
         ...
       } else {
         putc(c);
       }
```

Note: pedantic code would use the following as `is...()` functions are defined for all `int` values in the range of `unsigned char` and `EOF`.

```
isupper((unsigned char) c)
islower((unsigned char) c)
```

Note2: Code will have problems if `alphanum + key < 0`.  May want to add a test to insure `key` is not too negative or use the following to insure `key >= 0`.

```
int key = atoi(argv[1]) % 26 + 26;
```

Note3: OP's code assumes `A-Z` and `a-z` are consecutive like in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoding (which is certainly the case 99.99+% of the time.) but not in [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)